# When copying a block from an Eigen::Matrix to another block from the same matrix, what aliasing problems can occur?

Tags: eigen3

I want to copy a portion of a matrix into another part of the matrix itself, using Eigen. I want to make sure to understand the consequences, in terms of aliasing, in order to use `eval()` only when really needed.

Say that I have the following:

```
MatrixXd M(4,4);
M << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16;
M.block( some indices ) = M.block( some other indices )
```

I believe that there are 3 cases that should be considered:

## Case 1: the blocks do not overlap

This should not be a problem at all. An example would be:

```
M.topLeftCorner(2,2) = M.bottomRightCorner(2,2);
```

Giving us: [image: link to image]

## Case 2: the blocks overlap; the first position in the destination block comes before the first of the source

An example would be:

```
M.topLeftCorner(2,2) = M.block(1,0,2,2);
```

In this case, I would expect something like this to happen: [image: link to image]

which I believe would not be an example of aliasing. However, to obtain such a behavior, one would need the guarantee that elements are copied one by one in order, starting from the top-left one and proceeding row by row in the two blocks.

## Case 3: the blocks overlap; the first position in the destination block comes after the first of the source

Here, I would expect aliasing. An example would be:

```
M.block(1,0,2,2) = M.topLeftCorner(2,2);
```

with a result similar to: [image: link to image]

## Conclusion

To sum up:

1. I would *not* expect aliasing in the 1st case
2. Given the "ordered copy" assumption, I would not assume aliasing in the 2nd case
3. I would *always* expect aliasing in the 3rd case

Are these conclusions correct? Is the assumption of "ordered copy" true or not? I imagine that vectorization could actually invalidate this hypothesis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with point 1. If blocks don't overlap, you will have no aliasing issues.

However, for both 2. and 3. you may or may not have aliasing problems, depending on the Eigen version, target architecture and compiler -- essentially the outcome of these operations is undefined. I.e., you should not rely on the current behavior.

If you want to have some explicit behavior (without using temporaries), you can manually loop over non-overlapping blocks of your matrix. Instead of

```
M.topLeftCorner(2,2) = M.block(1,0,2,2);
```

you can write something like this:

```
for(int c=0; c<2; ++c)
    M.block(0,c,2,1) = M.block(0,c+1,2,1);
```

Or better, re-think your overall algorithm to avoid copying overlapping blocks inside your matrix.

For more details on aliasing see this page: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicAliasing.html